# jQuery: See how many elements a selector matched?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

If I have a selector like

```
$.('.active');
```

How can I see how many items that matched?

Alternatively, is there an easy way to see if more than zero elements were matched?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

call [`.length`](https://api.jquery.com/length/) on the returned set.

Do not use [`.size`](https://api.jquery.com/size/) because:

> The .size() method is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8

Answer (score 12):

How many:

```
var count = $('.active').length;
```

Check if it matched something:

```
if ($('.active').length) // since 0 == false
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the native javascript `length` property:

```
alert( $(".active").length );
```

You can even use the `.length` return value directly within a conditional statement:

```
if( $(".active").length ) {
  alert("Found some");  
} else {
  alert("Found nothing"); 
}​
```

In this example, if 0 results are found the else statement will be executed.

Example: http://jsbin.com/upabu/edit

Answer (score 2):

you should use `$('.class').length` because it is faster, but alternatively you can call `$('.class').size()` and get the same result.

To check the elements, do something like the following:

```
var len = $('.class').length;
if (len)
    // do something
else
    // do something else
```

Caching the length in a local var is an optimization that will speed up your JS if you have to make another call to that length property.

Comment: `.size()` is depricated! do not advice that