# Count child's length by using php or jquery

Tags: php, jquery

[image: here is the markup]

how to calculate the number of `<tr>` using php? or in jquery if it's not possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: See how many elements a selector matched?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838518/jquery-see-how-many-elements-a-selector-matched)

Comment: Duplicate of [jQuery - count number of rows in a table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149958/jquery-count-number-of-rows-in-a-table)

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery

```
var rowCount = $("table.iB tbody tr").length;
```

Comment: so it's not possible in php?

Comment: I dont know, I'm sure it is, but PHP isn't my specialty - and it's easy in JS

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery:

```
$('.iB >tr').length
```

or

```
$('.iB').find('tr').length
```